# Chrome-cast: seek bar position issue while streaming live video

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am playing live (DVR-enabled) video on Chromecast and facing issue with seekbar.

**Problem**

The problem is that while chrome-casting/steaming live video, current time is changing but seek bar is showing pointer in (left most) beginning as it should be in the right most so that user can go backward as shown in the screen shot below, also the final time is `00:00` where it should be the time as much as it has been played.

[image]

But playing on device is working fine and showing seek bar to the right most

[image]

*Receiver app is build using [CastReferencePlayer library](https://github.com/googlecast/CastReferencePlayer)*

*Sender android app is build using [CastVideos-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android)*

Source: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads

Comment: We are working on a better solution for live streams.

Comment: @LeonNicholls any update, sir?

Comment: We have launched the CAF receiver which has various improvements over the CastReferencePlayer. I recommend that you try that: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_overview